# Differences between Chrome and Firefox/Safari for session cookie storage

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies, web-development-server

I'm debugging an issue where I have a session cookie in my web app that is mysteriously expiring early in Chrome, but not in Firefox or Safari.

For example:

Chrome: I log into the web app, the cookie is stored. The cookie is used successfully for a few minutes, but then mysteriously after a few minutes it is expired.

Firefox/Safari: I log into the web app, the cookie is stored. The cookie is used successfully for hours (or until the session ends)

What I'm looking to learn:

1. Is there any major difference in how Chrome and Firefox/Safari handle session cookies that I am just completely missing?
2. Any debugging tips? (maybe enabling some debug logs for cookies in chrome?)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Firefox internally store all of their session state in sqlite database.

For Chrome, this column which stores the value of the cookie is encrypted when available with a master key that is unlocked only when your user is logged in. This protects from at-rest database attacks. In Linux this is libsecret. On Windows this is with DPAPI.

Safari stores its cookies in `~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies`. This file is a binary store and otherwise totally unencrypted. It's written to by a daemon. Previously, [`cookiesd` then `nsurlstoraged` and (now something else whatever it is.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/466143/76955) The format is proprietary, as is the class which writes it.